# Why does usblp prevent VMware from accessing my USB printer?

Tags: usb, kernel, printing, vmware

Every time I plug in my USB printer for VMware Workstation 9 to use (Windows 7 guest OS), Ubuntu 13.04 (the host) launches usblp and grabs the printer. VMware then throws up a dialog:

> The specified device is claimed by another driver (usblp) on the host operating system.

As a result, I can't use the printer in VMware. I'd like to stop Ubuntu's usblp from doing this. (I never want the printer used on the Linux host, just in the Windows guest.)

Googling this question produces only answers that are 5+ years old and don't work, like [running modprobe -r usblp](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-26958.html), which doesn't stop usblp from being invoked, or [editing /etc/hotplug/blacklist](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-228402-view-next.html), when /etc/hotplug doesn't seem to exist for Ubuntu 13.04.

The guest OS does have focus when I connect the printer, so that's not the problem. I also looked in VMware Workstation's "VM / Removable Devices" menu but didn't see anything obvious to affect the problem.

Does anyone have a modern way to suppress or disable usblp that works for Ubuntu 13.04?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to blacklist usblp you could put it in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, or add your own `.conf` file to `/etc/modprobe.d`

Overall blacklisting isn't a very satisfying even if it works for you.

Comment: Blacklisting made the dialog go away. However, all that happened is the printer shows up in "Devices and Printers" under the "Unknown" heading. Windows Update is supposed to install the driver automatically.  So I found [this documentation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2803-device-installation-settings.html) on making Windows install drivers, rebooted the Windows VM, and plugged in the printer. This time the printer appeared under "Printers and Faxes" (yay!) and I could install the driver using right-click + "Troubleshooting." I'll follow up later if all goes well.

Comment: All is well. The driver installed and I can print. It turns out that blacklisting isn't necessary: if usblp launches, simply clicking "OK" on the dialog lets the VM see the printer. The real problem was that my Windows VM was configured not to download drivers.